# How does python know when to pass in `self`?

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-descriptors

Consider a trivial example:

```
class C:
    @staticmethod
    def my_static_method():
        print("static")

    def my_instance_method(self):
        print("self")
```

When I call `C().my_static_method()`, python doesn't pass the instance of `C` into `my_static_method`, and the [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods) that `my_static_method` references doesn't expect an instance of `C`, either.

This makes sense.

But then when I call `C().my_instance_method()`, how does python know to pass the instance of `C` that I'm calling `my_instance_method` from in as an argument, without me specifying anything?

Comment: Because *function objects **are descriptors***. Read about how it works [in your own link](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods)

Comment: [Docs on method objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects): "the call `x.f()` is exactly equivalent to `MyClass.f(x)`"

Comment: For the record, I didn't downvote. And I think the downvotes are harsh. This isn't a bad question.

Comment: It's hard to write the answer I want for this, simply because I can't decide how much detail should be included on various technical aspects.

Comment: See also: https://eev.ee/blog/2012/05/23/python-faq-descriptors/ and then https://eev.ee/blog/2013/03/03/the-controller-pattern-is-awful-and-other-oo-heresy/. "what makes Python an object-oriented language? ...The answer is descriptors, which are basically “the things that make self work”. A descriptor object is an attribute of a class, and it’s invoked whenever that attribute is accessed on an instance of that class. "

Answer (score 2):

As the link explains, **function objects are descriptors!** Just like `staticmethod` objects.

They have a `__get__` method which *returns a bound-method object*, which essentially just partially applies the instance itself as the first positional argument. Consider:

```
>>> def foo(self):
...     return self.bar
...
>>> class Baz:
...     bar = 42
...
>>> baz = Baz()
>>> bound_method = foo.__get__(baz, Baz)
>>> bound_method
<bound method foo of <__main__.Baz object at 0x7ffcd001c7f0>>
>>> method()
42
```

Answer (score 1):

The key point here is that methods are *just functions that happen to be attributes of a class*. The actual magic, in Python, happens *in the attribute lookup process*. The link you give explains [earlier](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#invocation-from-an-instance) just how much happens every time `x.y` happens in Python. (Remember, *everything is an object*; that includes functions, classes, modules, `type` (which is an instance *of itself*)...)

This process is why descriptors can work at all; why we need explicit `self`; and why we can do fun things like calling a method with normal function call syntax (as long as we look it up *from the class* rather than an instance), alias it, mimic the method binding process with `functools.partial`....

Suppose we have `c = C()`. When you do `c.my_instance_method` (never mind calling it for now), Python looks for `my_instance_method` in `type(c)` (i.e., in the `C` class), and also checks if it's a descriptor, and also if it's specifically a data descriptor. Functions are non-data descriptors; even outside of a class, you can write

```
>>> def x(spam): return spam
...
>>> x.__get__
<method-wrapper '__get__' of function object at 0x...>
```

Because of the priority rules, as long as `c` doesn't directly have an attribute attached with the same name, the function will be found in `C` *and its `__get__` will be used*. Note that the `__get__` in question comes from the class - but it isn't using the same process as `x.__get__` above. That code looks in the class because that's one of the places checked for an attribute lookup; but when `c.my_instance_method` redirects to `C.my_instance_method.__get__`, it's looking there *directly* - attaching a `__get__` attribute directly to the function wouldn't change anything (which is why `staticmethod` is implemented as a class instead).

That `__get__` implements the actual method binding. Let's pretend we found `x` as a method in the `str` class:

```
>>> x.__get__('spam', str)
<bound method x of 'spam'>
>>> x.__get__('spam', str)()
'spam'
```

Remember, although the function in question takes three arguments, we're calling `__get__`, itself, *as a method* - so `x` gets bound to it in the same way. Equivalently, and more faithful to the actual process:

```
>>> type(x).__get__(x, 'spam', str)
<bound method x of 'spam'>
>>> type(x).__get__(x, 'spam', str)()
'spam'
```

So what exactly is that "bound method", anyway?

```
>>> bound = type(x).__get__(x, 'spam', str)
>>> type(bound)
<class 'method'>
>>> bound.__call__
<method-wrapper '__call__' of method object at 0x...>
>>> bound.__func__
<function x at 0x...>
>>> bound.__self__
'spam'
>>> type(bound)(x, 'eggs')
<bound method x of 'eggs'>
```

Pretty much what you'd expect: it's a callable object that stores and uses the original function and `self` value, and does the obvious thing in `__call__`.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the @staticmethod decorator to my_static_method, you told python not to pass the calling instance of C into the function. So you can call this function as C.my_static_method().

By calling C() you created an *instance* of C.  Then you called the non static function my_instance_method() which Python happily passed your new instance of C as the first parameter.

What happens when you call C.my_instance_method() ?

Rhetorical: You'll get a "missing one required arg self" exception -- since my_instance_method only works when calling from an instance unless you decorate it as static.

Of course you can still call the static member from an instance C().my_static_method() but you don't have a self param so no access to the instance.

Comment: You seem to have missed the point. The question is about *how* Python passes the instance as a parameter to the non-static method.